# How to send a push notification to iOS Wallet app using Typescript [Firebase]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, wallet

I am building an app that can create a store card and distribute it as a pass for the iOS Wallet app.

So far, I've implemented:

- Build a pass
- Distribute a pass
- Devices Register for Updates

Now I want to implement:

- Server Sends a Push Notification When Something Changes
  *the step from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html) page.

I did not find a document that explains how to send a push notification to the wallet app using Firebase and Typescript.